# Python Scikit-Learn RandomizedSearchCV with custom scoring functions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Scikit-Learn's Random Forest Regressor, Pipeline, and RandomizedSearchCV to predict the target variable using some features in my dataset. I need to use my own custom scoring functions that calculate weighted scores using weights (signifying the importance of observations) from the dataset. My code seems to work but I am getting a warning when the grid runs:

*`DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples,), for examples using ravel(). self.__final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)`*

This is related to `.fit(X_train, y_train)`. Based on this warning, if I change the code to `.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())` then I cannot get my weighted scores to work. I have tried editing the code in different/appropriate ways to get the weighted scores to work but to no avail.

I am including my code below that runs on a test data in `test.csv`. The file has four columns: two feature columns `('x1', 'x2')`, target `('y')` and weight `('weight')` columns. The custom scoring functions below are simple functions that calculate weighted rmse_score and mean_abs_error_score. How can I use `.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())` and still compute the scores?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn.model_selection as skms
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler



def rmse_score(y_true, y_pred, weight):
    weight = weight.loc[y_true.index.values]
    rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(weight*(y_true.values-y_pred)**2))
    return rmse


def mean_abs_error_score(y_true, y_pred, weight):
    weight = weight.loc[y_true.index.values]
    mae = np.mean(weight*np.absolute(y_true.values-y_pred))
    return mae

#----  reading data
heart_df = pd.read_csv('data\\test.csv')

#----  splitting into training & testing sets
y = heart_df['y']
X = heart_df[['x1', 'x2']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = skms.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)
    
X_train_weights = heart_df['weight'].loc[X_train.index.values]
params = {"weight": X_train_weights}

my_scorer1 = make_scorer(rmse_score, greater_is_better=False, **params)
my_scorer2 = make_scorer(mean_abs_error_score, greater_is_better=False, **params)

#----  random forest training with hyperparameter tuning
pipe = Pipeline([("scaler", StandardScaler()), ("rfr", RandomForestRegressor())])

random_grid = { "rfr__n_estimators": [10, 100, 500, 1000],
                "rfr__max_depth": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, None],
                "rfr__max_features": [0.25, 0.50, 0.75],
                "rfr__min_samples_split": [5, 10, 20],
                "rfr__min_samples_leaf": [3, 5, 10],
                "rfr__bootstrap": [True, False]
               }

rfr_cv = skms.RandomizedSearchCV(pipe, 
                              param_distributions=random_grid, 
                              n_iter = 15, 
                              cv = 3, 
                              verbose=3, 
                              scoring={'rmse': my_scorer1, 'mae':my_scorer2},
                              refit = 'rmse',
                              random_state=42, 
                              n_jobs = -1)

rfr_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_params = rfr_cv.best_params_
best_score = rfr_cv.best_score_

print(f'best hyperparameters = {best_params}')
print(f'best score = {best_score}')
```

Comment: `.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())` does it work?

Comment: thanks for your response! I tried y_train.ravel() but I get an error.
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Comment: yes, so that has been the issue. If I use .fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel()), then I cannot get my weighted custom scores to work.

Comment: well, then I guess you could try converting it into NumPy array from dataframe object first, something like `y_train.to_numpy()` should work.

Comment: I think the problem is that I am having to transfer the weights into my scoring functions using **arguments. I am using the index information in y_train to match the weights to CV sets within the scoring functions. If I convert y_train to an array, I lose the ability to match the weights in those functions.

Comment: @arqchicago any luck with this? I am experiencing the same issue.